# Shunting yard algorithm in Java not working?

Tags: java, postfix-notation, shunting-yard

Here is my code:

```
    public String ShuntingYard(String input) {
    Tokenizer tokens = new Tokenizer(input);
    output = new LinkedList<String>();
    stack = new MyStack<String>(new LinkedList<String>(), new LinkedList<String>());

    while (tokens.hasNextToken()){
        String token = tokens.getNextToken();
        if (isOperator(token)){
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && isOperator(stack.peek())){
                    if ((leftassoc(token)&&precedence(token)<=precedence(stack.peek())) ||
                            (precedence(token)<precedence(stack.peek()))){
                        output.add(stack.pop());
                    }
                    else break; }
                    stack.push(token);

                }

                output.add(token); 
            }
        while (!stack.isEmpty())
            output.add(stack.pop());

        return output.toString();

        }
```

With an input 3 + 5 * 6 + 7, it's supposed to return 3 5 6 * + 7 +, but instead I get 3 + 5 * 6 + 7 + *. I'm confused as to why, since I followed the algorithm instructions on the Wikipedia page...am I messing up somewhere else? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bascially you have a missing 'else'. Check the algorithm against your code. You're not handling the case correctly after the `if (isOperator())` branch is or isn't taken. You also haven't implemented '(' or ')'. There may be other errors or omissions.

Comment: See [my answer here](/questions/19721072/handling-parenthesis-while-converting-infix-expressions-to-postfix-expresssions) for a correct implementation.